# How can I provide multiple IPs in a single rule using AzureRm PowerShell?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-rm

I can configure a single rule successfully in my network security group with the following code for one source IP address (`$SourceAddressPrefix="x.x.x.x"`):

```
Set-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig  
    -NetworkSecurityGroup $nsg 
    -Name $name 
    -Direction Inbound  
    -Priority $priority 
    -Access Allow  
    -SourceAddressPrefix $sourcePrefix 
    -SourcePortRange *  
    -DestinationAddressPrefix * 
    -DestinationPortRange $destinationPortRange 
    -Protocol TCP 
 | Set-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup
```

I would like to configure this single rule for multiple IPs, but when I providing `$SourceAddressPrefix="x.x.x.x, y.y.y.y"` (just as I could do in Azure Portal interactively) I got the following error:

> "...has invalid Address prefix. Value provided: x.x.x.x, y.y.y.y"

**Question**

How can I provide multiple IPs in a single rule, just as I can do it in Azure Portal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to give it an array of values (because it expects `System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]`):

```
@("x.x.x.x", "y.y.y.y")
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.network/set-azurermnetworksecurityruleconfig?view=azurermps-6.13.0

Answer (score 4):

You could use this `$sourcePrefix = "x.x.x.x","y.y.y.y"`. This works on my side.

```
$nsg = Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -ResourceGroupName "xxx" -Name "xxx"
$name = "port_1433"
$priority = 600
$sourcePrefix = "1.1.1.1","2.2.2.2"
$destinationPortRange ="1433"
Set-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -NetworkSecurityGroup $nsg  -Name $name `
    -Direction Inbound  `
    -Priority $priority `
    -Access Allow  `
    -SourceAddressPrefix $sourcePrefix `
    -SourcePortRange *  `
    -DestinationAddressPrefix * `
    -DestinationPortRange $destinationPortRange `
    -Protocol TCP 
$nsg | Set-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup
```

[image]

Comment: thats basically copying my answer. why?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone also needs this and has a string of IPs like OP, you can do the following to split it by spaces into an Array.

```
$ips = '1.2.3.4 6.5.4.3 4.6.8.9'
$ipsSplit = $ips.Split(" ")
... 
-SourceAddressPrefix $ipsSplit `
...
```